# making use of neighbour finding and symmetry for runtime performance?

Tags: algorithm

Suppose I have a set of 3D points `{x[i], i=1,...,n}`, and

I have an array `A`, each entry `A[i]` of the array corresponds to some measurement of a point `x[i]`. If two points `x[i]` and `x[j]` are within a fixed distance `d` from each other, then we add some constant `f(x[i],x[j])`, computed by a function `f`, to both of their entries `A[i]` and `A[j]` in the array.

A direct way to compute the entries of the array `A` is (in pseudocode)

```
for i = 1,...,n
    A[i] = 0

for i = 1,...,n
    for j = i,...,n
        if dist(x[i],x[j]) < d
            tmp = f(x[i],x[j])
            A[i]+= tmp
            A[j]+= tmp
```

If I also have a function `find_nb(x[i])`, which takes a point `x[i]` as an argument and returns a set of points within the fixed distance `d` from the point `x[i]`, including the point `x[i]` itself, and the number of them, I wonder how this function can help to improve the run time performance (such as time and/or space) of the above algorithm?

Following is the way I thought of:

```
for i = 1,...,n
    A[i] = 0

for i = 1,...,n
    (nbs, num) = find_nb(x[i])
    for j = 1,...,num
        A[i]+=f(x[i],x[nbs[j]])
```

But it doesn't make use of the symmetry between every two points, i.e. we have to calculate `f(x[i],x[nbs[j]])` twice, for`A[i]`  and `A[nbs[j]]`. It is a waste. So can this be improved?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there's a bug in your code: When i = j, you add tmp twice, both to a [i] and a [j] which are the same array element.

Quite obviously the function doesn't return a set of points, but a set of indices of points, so the improvement is quite simple:

```
for i = 1,...,n
    (nbs, num) = find_nb(x[i])
    for k = 1,...,num
        j = nbs [k]
        if (j >= i)
            tmp = f (x [i], x [j])
            A[i]+=tmp
            if (j != i)
                a [j] += tmp
```